# React Native, set id of selected index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to set id of selected item but getting error:

> TypeError: setTagsId is not a function. (In 'setTagsId(tag_id)', 'setTagsId' is undefined)

Below is my code:

```
const tags = [  {
      "_id": "601d720be401f8f25964060e",
      "name": "Testing",
      "is_clicked": false,
      "is_blocked": false,
      "is_deleted": false,
      "created_at": "1612530997069"
    },
    {
      "_id": "60110256f7af958907ac5813",
      "name": "cafe",
      "is_blocked": false,
      "is_deleted": false,
      "created_at": "1611639739319",
      "is_clicked": false
    },]
const [tagsId, setTagsId] = useState([]);

 const onDuplicateMeeting = async () => {
    let tag_id = tags.map((data) => {
      return data._id;
    });
    setTagsId(tag_id);
    const checkValid = isValid();
    if (checkValid) {
      setState({...state, isLoading: true});
      try {
        const res = await actions.addNewMeetingRoom({
          tags: tagsId,
        });
        setState({...state, isLoading: false});
        navigation.navigate(strings.NAV_MANAGE_MEETING_ROOM);
      } catch (error) {
        showError(error);
        console.log(error);
        setState({...state, isLoading: false});
      }
    }
  };
...
   <ButtonWithLoader
          btnText={strings.CONFIRM_SUBMIT}
          btnStyle={{
            marginHorizontal: moderateScale(16),
          }}
          onPress={onDuplicateMeeting}
        />
```

is there something wrong in code? can someone please help?

Comment: Can you please post your full component code? Just to see how you are using the `return` part. Thanks!

Comment: ya sure, done...

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring from `useState` as `[]` instead of `{}` might solve the issue. Try as:

```
const [tagsId, setTagsId] = useState([]);
```

Suggested read is [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), especially the [Declaring a State Variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) section.

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {statusCode, error, message, type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` got that error

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong code in useState

`const [value, updateValueFunction]= useState(initialValue)`

in the above code you have used `{}` where `[]` is needed.

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {statusCode, error, message, type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` got that error